# Вывод списка файлов в директории

Tags: golang

При попытке отправки списка файлов находящихся в директории, список файлов отображается лишь в самой косноли при вызове команды, что странно, названия файлов выводятся поочерёдно в консоли, но сам бот ничего не отправляет.

```
if Text == "dir" {

    file, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
     for _, files := range file {

           f := files.Name()

           f += files.Name() + "\n"

           msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID,f)

           bot.Send(msg)
}

}
```

Comment: Все правильно, в консоли отображается это `files.Name()`, а в чат вы отправляете это - `f`. Эту переменную вы инициализировали, но ничего ей не присвоили, поэтому в чат уходит пустая строка

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему, только образовалась еще одна, каждый файл который находится в папке, отправляется отдельным сообщением в чат, как можно отправить список файлов одним сообщением?

Comment: Чтобы отправить все за раз, нужно сначала собрать все имена, а потом отправить один раз уже после цикла. Собрать можно в ту же переменную `f` - вынесете инициализацию перед циклом. В самом цикле можно добавлять в нее новое имя - `f += files.Name() + "\n"`

Comment: Не помогло, можно развернутый ответ? Я правильно все сделал? f := files.Name() f += files.Name() + "\n"

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос лучше, вставив текущий код и какой вы получаете результат. А то так не очень понятно

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: `f := files.Name()` нужно убрать, перед циклом поставить `var f string`. И `msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID,f)` после цикла

Comment: Теперь список файлов выводится в одном собщении, но уже по нарастающей. К примеру в папке всего 4 файла:1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt. Вывод происходит следующим образом. "1.txt" "1.txt,2.txt" "1.txt,2.txt,3.txt" и так далее.

Comment: Значит вы отправку сообщения не вынесли из цикла. Нужно отправлять после выхода `for`